# Why does my python input function asks for input twice?

Tags: python, function, writetofile

Basically you choose how many lines, then it prints random numbers to file.
The program works but I need to input the number twice.

```
import random
import datetime

def getInput():

    try:
        user = int(input("How many lines? "))
        if user > 14:
            print("Max 14!")
            getInput()
        else:
            return user
    except ValueError:
        print("Numbers Only!")
        getInput()

def go(user):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    num = 0
    f = 'C:/Users/Gilush/Desktop/lot.txt'
    with open(f,'a') as file:
        file.write(f'{now.strftime("%d.%m.%y")}\n\n')
        while num < user:
            rand = random.sample(range(1,37), 6)
            rand.sort()
            s = random.sample(range(1,8), 1)
            file.write(f'{rand},{s}\n')
            num += 1
        file.write('======\n')
        file.close()

getInput()
go(user=getInput())
```

Comment: Remember - `getInput` needs to return a value on all paths. Change those internal calls to `return getInput()` or the input will be lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response). You're trying to validate an acceptable input and doing in incorrectly.  The duplicate shows how to do this.

Comment: @tdelaney can you show me an example? I got lost trying to fix that issue as well. Thank you!

Comment: That post helped alot! (bookmarked). Thank you very much!

Comment: I've posted a full working fix. Mine is just an FYI, the first answer is the official answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getInput()
go(user=getInput())
```

This calls `getInput` twice. One time on each line.

You probably want:

```
user = getInput()
go(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
getInput()
go(user=getInput())
```

do you see you are calling `getInput` twice

maybe you want to do

```py
user = getInput()
go(user)

# or
# go(user = getInput())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use user to take getInput() and go the value in user as go(user)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you've called `getInput` twice. There was a second issue about propegating `getInput` results back to the original caller. Here is the script with both fixes.

```
import random
import datetime

def getInput():

    try:
        user = int(input("How many lines? "))
        if user > 14:
            print("Max 14!")
            return getInput()
        else:
            return user
    except ValueError:
        print("Numbers Only!")
        return getInput()

def go(user):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    num = 0
    # todo: removed for test
    # f = 'C:/Users/Gilush/Desktop/lot.txt'
    f = 'lot.txt'
    with open(f,'a') as file:
        file.write(f'{now.strftime("%d.%m.%y")}\n\n')
        while num < user:
            rand = random.sample(range(1,37), 6)
            rand.sort()
            s = random.sample(range(1,8), 1)
            file.write(f'{rand},{s}\n')
            num += 1
        file.write('======\n')
        file.close()

user = getInput()
go(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Rewrite `getInput` and add `def main()`

#### `getInput`

```py
def getInput():
    while True:
        try:
            user = int(input("How many lines? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Numbers Only!")
            continue
        if user > 14:
            print("Max 14!")
            continue
        else:
            return user
```

#### `def main()`

```py
def main():
    user_input = getInput()
    go(user_input)
```

#### full program

```py
def getInput():
    while True:
        try:
            user = int(input("How many lines? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Numbers Only!")
            continue
        if user > 14:
            print("Max 14!")
            continue
        else:
            return user


def go(user):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    num = 0
    f = 'C:/Users/Gilush/Desktop/lot.txt'
    with open(f,'a') as file:
        file.write(f'{now.strftime("%d.%m.%y")}\n\n')
        while num < user:
            rand = random.sample(range(1,37), 6)
            rand.sort()
            s = random.sample(range(1,8), 1)
            file.write(f'{rand},{s}\n')
            num += 1
        file.write('======\n')
        file.close()


def main():
    user_input = getInput()
    go(user_input)


main()
```